# automated hyperlink

Tags: vba

I am trying to create a Macro which would create an hyperlink based on the content of an active cell.

Let's assume that in cell A1, there is a reference to cell B29 (i.e. "=B29"),

If my active cell is A1, I would like "=B29" to be replaced by "=HYPERLINK("#"&CELL("address",B29),B29)" when I run the Macro.

I want this macro to work only with the active cell. Is this possible?

I woudld appreciate if you could help me.

I tried the following but it is not working:

```
Sub hyperlinktocell()
    Dim num1 As Integer
    Dim celladress As String

    num1 = Len(ActiveCell.Formula) - 1
    celladdress = Right(ActiveCell.Formula, num1)
    ActiveCell.Formula = "=HYPERLINK(""#""&CELL(""address"",celladdress,celladdress)"
End Sub
```

I am new to VBA and spent almost 2 hours to get the above right without any success.

Comment: I just tried and it can be done no problem in 3 lines. You will need to use `ActiveCell` and its `Formula` property. I also used `Right()` and `Len()` to get the proper formula. This should be enough to get you started.

Comment: Thank you Alex. I tried waht you suggested (see above) but I did not manage to make it work. Would appreciate your help.

Comment: This is because you are using `celladdress` as text, not as the variable. You need to end the text with a close double-quote and then concatenate using & like so : `"this is a string " & my_variable & " this is another string"`

Comment: Thank you Alex. Your help was very much appreciated. Have a good day. Thomas

Answer (score 1):

Since you've done almost all the work, I'll post you what I had:

```
Private Sub test()
    Dim s As String
    s = Right(ActiveCell.Formula, Len(ActiveCell.Formula) - 1)
    ActiveCell.Formula = "=HYPERLINK(""#""&CELL(""address""," & s & ")," & s & ")"
End Sub
```

As you can see, apart from using one less variable we have the same solution. Notice on the last line how I concatenate the string. In your code you have all those variables inside the double quotes, which makes them text. Then Excel complains that this isn't a valid value for this property which is right.